# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'babel') at module.exports (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:103:36)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I have a react project, and I have implemented all the webpack.config.cjs, .babelrc files in my root folder. But my project is not able to proceed further from index.js file saying this:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'babel')
    at module.exports (/Users/sachinsingh/Lab Medical App/Frontend/frontend-lab-medical-app/react-app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:103:36)

webpack 5.89.0 compiled with 1 error and 1 warning in 830 ms
```

I am very troubled and unable to understand what this is, I would be very grateful if anybody can help me with this.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]

}
```

webpack.config.cjs

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js', // Your main entry file
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Output directory for bundled files
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Transpile JavaScript with Babel
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html', // HTML template file
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), // Serve files from the 'dist' directory
    },
    port: 3000, // Port for the development server
  },
};
```

```js
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.12",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.147",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.15",
    "@mui/system": "^5.14.11",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.16.1",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/core": "^3.12.0",
    "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.1.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.31",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "appwrite": "^13.0.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "flatted": "^3.2.9",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "pdfjs-dist": "2.6.347",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.19.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-image": "^4.1.0",
    "react-image-gallery": "^1.3.0",
    "react-pdf": "^7.5.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-viewer": "^3.2.2",
    "rfdc": "^1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.8",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.cjs",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import MedicalRecord from './components/MedicalRecord';
import Signup from './components/Auth/Signup';
import AuthApp from './components/Auth/AuthApp';

import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
   <AuthApp/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

All the files that I changed are given above.